# Changing CCSpriteSheet to CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have tried to change CCSpriteSheet to CCSpriteBatchNode as it is deprecated.

Before:

```
ss = [[CCSpriteSheet alloc] initWithFile:spriteFile capacity:frameCount];
```

After:

```
ss = [[CCSpriteBatchNode alloc] initWithFile:spriteFile capacity:frameCount];
```

I get the following warning:

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'CCSpriteSheetInternalOnly *' from 'CCSpriteBatchNode *'

I'm quite new to this, and have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: how do you declare ss ?

Comment: - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)animEntry {
 if( (self = [super init]) ) {  ss = nil;

Comment: was looking for the declaration :  maybe in your .h, or a few lines above offending lines. You must have a CCSomething *ss = [CCSomething ...]; line

Comment: Oh sorry
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface GameAnimation : CCNode {
 CCSpriteSheetInternalOnly *ss;